# How do I see which user accounts are available to systemd for launching services on system startup?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, active-directory, systemctl

I have a systemd service that fails to launch on system startup with error code `status=217/USER` (see below), which means D001615 (AD user) does not exist according to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/376838/how-to-get-linux-users-list-from-ldap).

However, if I restart the service manually using root, then it runs fine as D001615:

```
[root@host.example.net SYST:~]# ps -Af --forest | grep runsvc
root      1439  1293  0 09:52 pts/0    00:00:00                          \_ grep --color=auto runsvc
d001615   1340     1  0 09:51 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /opt/azagent/runsvc.sh
```

I am not a system administrator, I just know the Linux server is configured to use Active Directory.

**How can I see, which user accounts are available to systemd to run services on startup**? I have attempted `getent passwd`, but it does not list other accounts besides those in `/etc/passwd` - in particular, no POSIX entries from LDAP server are displayed.

**How can I configure systemd to run services as D001615 on system startup**?

NB: I am able to `su d001615` to change from root to D001615, so indeed D001615 exist as a user on the host.

```
systemctl status -l 'vsts.agent.azuredevops.Application\x20Security\x2dsds.host.example.net.service' 
● vsts.agent.azuredevops.Application\x20Security\x2dsds.host.example.net.service - Azure Pipelines Agent (azuredevops.Application Security-sds.host.example.net)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.azuredevops.Application\x20Security\x2dsds.host.example.net.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-11-24 06:17:35 CET; 3h 13min ago
  Process: 2071 ExecStart=/opt/azagent/runsvc.sh (code=exited, status=217/USER)
 Main PID: 2071 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

cat /etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.azuredevops.Application\x20Security\x2dsds.host.example.net.service
[Unit]
Description=Azure Pipelines Agent (azuredevops.Application Security-sds.host.example.net)
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/azagent/runsvc.sh
User=d001615
WorkingDirectory=/opt/azagent
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGTERM
TimeoutStopSec=5min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You could try adding another dependency to the unit. I dont know if active-directory provides its own "ready" target, but you should look for one such as `nss-user-lookup.target`.

Comment: @meuh - I have another server that uses D001617 as the service user. That service starts up perfectly. Do you know how to list users, both local and Active Directory, that are allowed to login to the local system?

Comment: seconding meuh's comment, we've edited systemd unit files to be "After" the service that provides non-local users. You may want to consult the system administrator to see if they can guide you to that service name.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - will you elaborate? What's the service called that provides non-local users? What service service name should I consult with the system administrator?

Comment: It sounds like yours is provided by LDAP; you'd just need to order this service to be after the LDAP one. Separately, you might try `getent passwd d001615` to explicitly request that user entry; perhaps the LDAP service does not allow enumeration of the available users.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - what service would normally be used for LDAP? Do you know the names of some common ones? Isn’t `getent` merely listing the contents of `/etc/passwd`? In my case D001615 is not listed in it.

Comment: It's possible that your system adminisatrator has set up sssd, but meuh has a good point about looking for a more-generic target that would ensure user lookups are ready. I'm guessing you're hitting "good luck" with the other system booting to that target in time for the azure service to succeed. Better to ensure success when you know there's a dependency. Ask your system administrator, or check via systemctl, which targets/services are available.